# Not able to delete user synced from Windows server using Azure AD Connect

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I created a Windows server 2012 R2 VM in the Azure and I made it as Windows domain controller.

I created some users in the windows server lets say user@xyz.com

In the Azure portal I created a Custom domain lets say it as xyz.com which I purchased from godaddy.

I installed Azure AD Connect in the Windows server and synced the Window Server AD with Azure AD and  Azure AD got the users from the windows Server

Now I deleted the Windows server VM.

Now when I try to delete the custom domain xyz.com the portal says I need to delete the user user1@xyz.com

But I am not able to delete the user1@xyz.com because the delete option is disabled.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

**CAUSE:**

The on-premises AD DS is no longer available. Therefore, you can't manage or delete the object from the on-premises environment.

**Solution:**

1. Install the Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell. For more info, go to the following Microsoft website:

[Manage Azure AD using Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/MSOnline/?view=azureadps-1.0&redirectedfrom=msdn)

2. Connect to Azure AD by using Windows PowerShell.
3. Disable directory synchronization. To do this, type the following cmdlet, and then press Enter:

   `Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled –EnableDirSync $false`
4. Check that directory synchronization was fully disabled by using the Windows PowerShell. To do this, run the following cmdlet periodically:

   `(Get-MSOLCompanyInformation).DirectorySynchronizationEnabled`

   This cmdlet will return True or False. Continue to run this cmdlet periodically until it returns False, and then go to the next step.

**Note** It may take 72 hours for deactivation to be completed. The time depends on the number of objects that are in your cloud service subscription account.

5. Try to remove/update an object by using Windows PowerShell or by using the portal.

See more details about this kind of case Official support article in [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2619062/you-can-t-manage-or-remove-objects-that-were-synchronized-through-the).